# In Ruby on Rails, why http://localhost:3000/foobars/alt/1.xml not work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In Ruby on Rails,

```
http://localhost:3000/foobars/alt/1
```

works

but

```
http://localhost:3000/foobars/alt/1.xml
```

doesn't work.

`config/route.rb` is

```
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
```

so supposedly it supports an `id.format` in the URL?

Comment: When you say "doesn't work" what do you mean? There are a few ways it could be breaking, we won't know what's wrong until you let us know what you're expecting and what you're getting

Comment: yes, it says Template is missing: 

Missing template foobars/alt.erb in view path app/views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that your controller action has a respond to block that supports XML:

```
def alt
    @object = ...

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.xml { render :xml => @object.to_xml }
    end
end
```

Comment: great, and it looks like if alt.xml.erb exists in the views folder, it would work too.